# KeyError when enumerating over dataloader

Tags: python, pytorch, keyerror, dataloader

I'm trying to iterate over a pytorch dataloader initialized as follows:

trainDL = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(X_train,batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, shuffle=True, **kwargs)

where X_train is a pandas dataframe like this one:
[image: my pandas DF]

So, I'm not being able to do the following statement, since I'm getting a KeyError in the 'enumerate':

```
for batch_idx, (data, _) in enumerate(trainDL):
    {stuff}
```

has anyone a clue of what's happening?

EDIT:

The error I get is:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~/.local/share/virtualenvs/Pipenv-l_wD1rT4/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2896             try:
-> 2897                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2898             except KeyError:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 40592

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-63-95142e0748bb> in <module>
----> 1 for batch_idx, (data, _) in enumerate(trainDL):
      2     print(".")

~/.local/share/virtualenvs/Pipenv-l_wD1rT4/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py in __next__(self)
    344     def __next__(self):
    345         index = self._next_index()  # may raise StopIteration
--> 346         data = self._dataset_fetcher.fetch(index)  # may raise StopIteration
    347         if self._pin_memory:
    348             data = _utils.pin_memory.pin_memory(data)

~/.local/share/virtualenvs/Pipenv-l_wD1rT4/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py in fetch(self, possibly_batched_index)
     42     def fetch(self, possibly_batched_index):
     43         if self.auto_collation:
---> 44             data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
     45         else:
     46             data = self.dataset[possibly_batched_index]

~/.local/share/virtualenvs/Pipenv-l_wD1rT4/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py in <listcomp>(.0)
     42     def fetch(self, possibly_batched_index):
     43         if self.auto_collation:
---> 44             data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
     45         else:
     46             data = self.dataset[possibly_batched_index]

~/.local/share/virtualenvs/Pipenv-l_wD1rT4/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2993             if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   2994                 return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 2995             indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   2996             if is_integer(indexer):
   2997                 indexer = [indexer]

~/.local/share/virtualenvs/Pipenv-l_wD1rT4/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2897                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2898             except KeyError:
-> 2899                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
   2900         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)
   2901         if indexer.ndim > 1 or indexer.size > 1:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 40592
```

Comment: Show the actual error.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have to create `torch.utils.data.Dataset` wrapping your dataset.

For example:

```
from torch.utils.data import Dataset

class PandasDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, dataframe):
        self.dataframe = dataframe

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.dataframe)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.dataframe.iloc[index]
```

Pass this object to `DataLoader` instantiated by your pandas dataframe and you should be fine.

Example usage with `DataLoader`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
dataset = PandasDataset(df)
dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=16)
for sample in dataloader:
    ...
```

Comment: Hello, quite interesting approach. Could you provide an example on how to use this for a dataloader? Personally Im using a default pytorch training setup.

Comment: @GeorgePetropoulos added an example

Comment: With the above code, I get the below error:
TypeError: default_collate: batch must contain tensors, numpy arrays, numbers, dicts or lists; found Pandas.series

Comment: @RajaC cast the output to ‘torch.Tensor’  (dataframe at least)

Comment: I'm running into the same error, but I have image files that I load into dataset as follows: train_ds = torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder('/content/train/', transform=ToTensor()). Then I use the dataloader: train_loader = data.DataLoader(train_ds, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, shuffle=True,  num_workers=4). I get this error when I enumerate like this: for step, (x, y) in enumerate(train_loader). Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same error. Turns out that the issue was with label (i.e. y) array.
The labels that I was using to make a custom dataset and then the dataset was being used in dataloader. This labels array was actually coming from a pandas dataframe and it still contained the original indices from pandas.

Simple doing labels.to_numpy() and then using labels in the custom dataset resolved the issue.